# PHP: ZipArchive::extractTo doesn't working (Errror)

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm completely at a loss for explaining why this isn't working.

```
$filename = 'zipfile.zip';
$za = new ZipArchive();
$folder = DIR_UPLOAD . $filename;
$za->open($folder);
$za->extractTo(DIR_UPLOAD . 'unzip/');
$za->close();
```

> Error: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

I tried so many solution for solving this error, But i still facing this error.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: what is the value of `DIR_UPLOAD`

Comment: DIR_UPLODD is folder name that i definef.

Comment: **ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object** this error i facing.

Comment: Is that your whole code? add more because your current code just works fine. either you zip corrupted or you are closing the zip before extract

Comment: Check i have updated the answer, Your zip location is wrong./

Comment: Yes, you are right my zip location is wronng

Comment: Upvote and accept my answer if that fixes your issue , Happy coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Means your zip path is wrong. Check your `DIR_UPLOAD`

This script works fine for me

```
$filename = 'sample.zip';
$za = new ZipArchive();
$folder = $filename;
$za->open($folder);
$za->extractTo('unzip/');
$za->close();
```

also set the right file permission for `unzip` folder.

add these lines end of the code and see the last error

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(error_get_last());
```